# Error: Could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-build

I have created a Flutter project in Android Studio. It runs fine on Android devices but when I try to run it on Xcode, I get an error as:

> Build system information error:
> /Users/Downloads/flutter_wallpaper-master
> 2/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
> 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')

Can anyone help me with how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 127):

Try running `flutter build ios` and then rerun in Xcode

Comment: it doesn't work for me, after execution the cmd, I still get the error

Comment: after issuing this command, I had to then run some kind of recommended update in xcode to update target ios versions and then it started working.

Answer (score 71):

I assume you have already `ios/` folder in your Flutter project. If not, you can run `flutter build ios`.

The root cause of this error most of the times happens after you have cloned a project like from Github.

In order to fix, you need to get the packages and install the pods.

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && cd ios/ && pod install
```

(In some situation you might need to update your Pod Repo and Pods. You can do that via running `pod repo update && pod update`)

Comment: Não funcionou pra mim

Answer (score 31):

## Please follow these steps/run commands

1. `flutter clean` (in terminal)
2. `flutter build` (in terminal)
3. In Xcode, then build your project

The error should have gone now :)

Comment: For me skipping step 3 did the trick. It seemed counter intuitive to clean what was built in step 2.

Comment: finally worked!

Answer (score 4):

After few hours of search, this solved my issue.

Firstly, run flutter doctor to check if all the dependencies checked. Follow the instructions shown on the terminal if those [] boxes are not completed as [ticked].

```
flutter channel master
flutter doctor
```

Then, run this line.

```
flutter pub get
```

Lastly, use the following code to rebuild your ios path (assume your ios codes are stored in /ios folder of your project). This step already included the pod install procedure. No need for further `pod install` execution.

```
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Flutter project needs to be build on the XCode Cloud server, before the XCode project is built. This is achieved by adding a post-clone script described [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#custom-build-script). That is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with flavors, I was trying to set up different xcconfigs and setting FLUTTER_TARGET to a custom one. I created the xcconfig using Xcode. And builds were failing with this same issue (could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig')

[image: How it looks on Xcode]

Then checked the `ios/Flutter` folder on VSCode and saw that the newly created xcconfigs were not present there instead they were inside `ios`  folder:

[image]

Therefore had to change the Generated.xcconfig path to:

`#include "Flutter/Generated.xcconfig"`

instead and it works fine now.
A bit misleading from Xcode to show the new xcconfig inside the Flutter folder, but checking normal paths helped me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1.) flutter clean
2.) flutter pub get
3.) cd iOS
4.) pub update
5.) flutter run

=> should solve the problem.

If not -> delete the podfile and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

## My answer

In my case, the XCode Cloud build was failing but the local builds were succeeding. Turns out the reason was my flutter project was in a subdirectory of the repo. I had to add a `cd myflutterproj` to `ci_post_clone.sh` right after the `cd $CI_WORKSPACE`. Then XCode Cloud builds succeeded.

## What happened

`ci_post_clone.sh` was running the `flutter pub get` which failed but that failure did not bubble up because no one called `set -e` before that. So Xcode Cloud was thinking that `ci_post_clone.sh` succeeded and continued on as though everything was good, only to later fail because the flutter stuff wasn't generated.

I've opened https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/9342

Answer (score 0):

If the file 'Generated.xcconfig' has been generated, follow these steps:

1. open ios/Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode
2. In the left panel, open 'Generated.xcconfig', copy its content, and then delete the file.
3. Right-click on Runner/Flutter and select New File...
4. Choose "Configuration Settings File" and save it as "Generated".
5. Paste the content copied in step 2 into this new file and then rerun the project.