# Can't get Flutter project running after cloning from GitHub

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I'm new to Flutter and have been learning it recently. Been trying to get this flutter app running for my internship, but can't seem to figure out why it's not running. I have no problem getting the default flutter app running on both iOS and Android simulators and on my personal iPhone. Flutter doctor checks out fine. I’ve tried flutter clean, removing the Podfile (as it recommended because it said it was out of date), downgrading flutter to the same version my team was using because I was thinking maybe it was a problem with that working with Xcode 12, and running things like pub get and pod install. Same error all around when trying on Xcode, terminal, android studio, and VScode. I've been pretty much going in circles with the same errors trying different things.

I'm running the app with the following command: flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart --flavor dev

The third image is the error I got after I tried the first solution on Stackoverflow.

The fourth image is when I try running the app on my android sim.

I've tried the following answers here in Stack overflow

[First solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321180/error-could-not-find-included-file-generated-xcconfig-in-search-paths-in-tar)

[When I was getting deployment warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter)

[image: Flutter doctor -v results]

[image]

[image]

[image: error when running on Android simulator]

I could go on with the bunch of different errors I've encountered trying to run on Vscode, android studio, and so on, but basically, I've been going in circles with the same errors and the images below are just the ones I'm encountering now. All I'm trying to do is run the project I cloned from Github. I'm hoping anyone here will find an error that looks familiar to them or a similar situation where they couldn't get a flutter project to run after cloning.

Answer (score 1):

A word of advice, Always run the latest flutter engine unless it is absolutely necessary.

run `flutter clean`

run `rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock`

Looks like your `flutter svg` package has to be updated